# SIMULAR CLICK EM UM <a href via SELENIUM WEBDRIVER

Tags: java

estou percorrendo um TABLE na ultima coluna tenho um link que abre um alert, mas não estou conseguindo simular o click com o Selenium, será que alguem pode me ajudar?

```
td class="aligncenter">
a href="javascript:void(0);" title="Visualizar Texto" onclick="BuscarTextoDecisoesPop("1537784");">
img src="../img/Find.png" style="height:20px;width:20px;" alt="Visualizar Texto">
/a>
/td>
```

Desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Acho que achei a solução.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@title='Visualizar Texto']")).click();
```